# nock for axios mockup on 400 does not return the defined value

Tags: reactjs, axios, chai, nock

I am using nock to mock my ajax call with axios.
Here is my code:

```
    describe("unSuccessful rest call",()=>{

    it('should dispatch types: SET_DROP_DOWN_CHECK_STATUS in order ', () => {
        nock(getRootUrl(ServiceUrls.prototype.getContactUsUrl())).get(getExtention(ServiceUrls.prototype.getContactUsUrl())).replyWithError(400, "test");


        const expectedActions = [
            {
                "type": SET_DROP_DOWN_CHECK_STATUS,
                "payload": "test"
            }
        ];


        return store.dispatch(setContactUsList({push:()=>{}})).then(() => {
            expect(store.getActions()[0]).to.eql(expectedActions[0]);

        })
    })


})
```

When I run the above test it hits the server and return the actual error message instead of test which I asked for.
Interestingly when I use the above code for 200 it successfully returns what I define.
Can anyone help what is wrong with my approach?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is wrong with nock as I tried to use it and ran into similar issues. I use `axios-mock-adapter` and found that a simpler tool to work with.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import MockAdapter from 'axios-mock-adapter';

const mock = new MockAdapter(axios);

afterEach(() => {
    mock.reset();
});

it('should fail when trying to search for documents', async () => {

        mock.onGet(SEARCH_ENDPOINT + formattedFields).reply(400, {
            details: [
                {
                    code: 400,
                    message: 'No claim number or DCN provided'
                }
            ]
        });

        const given = { fields: activeFields };
        const expected = [
            { type: types.FETCH_DOCS_STARTED },
            { type: types.FETCH_DOCS_FAILED, message: 'No claim number or DCN provided' }
        ];

        await store.dispatch(actions.fetchDocs(given));

        const actualDispatchedActions = store.getActions();
        expect(actualDispatchedActions).toEqual(expected);
    });
```